# AngularJS custom sort filter for file size

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frontend

I have a column where title is file size and the data is in string format which is like " 1.2 Mb , 2.4 Kb , 241 Bytes..."

I have applied angular sorting on it using orderBy but its not working correctly.
It just shuffles values on God knows what logic.

A solution i have thought of is to convert the string into some integer/float and then sort the column on the basis of those integers/ floats.

Any idea how can i achieve this ? Like how can i convert these file sizes into some integers and apply sorting on it ? What code will i write in the function ?

I believe we would have to apply a check on the string for Mb, Kb or Bytes....etc.

Comment: Please include some relevant code in your question (View + Controller)

Comment: orderBy function on a string will not give you the desired sorting for a combination of numbers and letters. You need to make a custom comparator for this. Compare first on Mb, Kb,... then on the nummeric part.

Comment: I would suggest keeping size in bytes if you can. Then on your UI you can use a filter on how to display that - e.g. display '1024' as '1 MB'.
p.s. **MB** = Megabyte, **Mb** = Megabit

Answer (score 0):

If you have decimal data on your row, you can use simple orderBy

I created example for you,

```
        var controllers = {};
        var app = angular.module('UM',[]);

        //routing
        app.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                template: '<a href="#" class="btn">home</a><input ng-model="sorter" /><table  class="table table-striped">    <thead>        <th >            <a href="" ng-click="sortList(\'id\')">ID</a>        </th>        <th>            <a href="" ng-click="sortList(\'firstname\')">First Name</a>        </th>        <th>            <a href="" ng-click="sortList(\'lastname\')">Surname</a>        </th>        <th>            <a href="" ng-click="sortList(\'age\')">Age</a>        </th>        <th>           <a href="" ng-click="sortList(\'cars\')">cars</a>        </th>    </thead>    <tbody>        <tr ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:sorter ">            <td>{{person.id | number}}</td>            <td>{{person.firstname}} </td>            <td>{{person.lastname}} </td>            <td>{{person.age | number}}</td>            <td>{{person.cars}} </td>        </tr>    </tbody></table>',
                controller: 'listCtrl'
            }).when('/test',{
                template: '<h6>{{people}}</h6>',
                controller: 'listCtrl'
            });
        });

        //user data
        app.service('People', function() {
            var People = {};
            People.details = [{"id":"42","firstname":"Sarah","lastname":"Dilby","age":"33.1","cars":"Yaris"},
                              {"firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Diry","age":"32.1","id":"5"},
                              {"id":"6","firstname":"Bilson","lastname":"Berby","age":"33.3","cars":"Tipo"}]
            return People;
        });

        //list ctrl
        controllers.listCtrl = function ($scope,People) {
            $scope.people = People.details;
            $scope.sortList = function(sortname) {
                $scope.sorter = sortname;
            }
        }

        //controllers
        app.controller(controllers);
```

Check on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsbGH/14/)

Comment: Ok how exactly is this working ?...how is it differentiating between "33.1" and "32.1"....since both are string..?

Comment: I see you have done something like : <td>{{person.age | number}}</td>...here is this converting into a number ?

Comment: But my code is a little different :  <tr ng-click="viewFiles({{files.id}})"
                            ng-repeat="files in FileObject | orderBy:fileOrder:reverse">
                            <td>{{files.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{files.size | Filesize}}</td>
                        </tr>

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom comparator in orderBy directive. See documentation [angular orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```js
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.files = [
    {name: 'File1', size: '1.2 Mb'},
    {name: 'File2', size: '2.4 Kb'},
    {name: 'File3', size: '241 Bytes'},
    {name: 'File4', size: '2.0 Mb'},
    {name: 'File5', size: '16.1 Kb'}
  ];

  $scope.fileSizeComparator = function(s1, s2) {
    // split the size string in nummeric and alphabetic parts
    var s1Splitted = s1.value.split(" ");
    var s2Splitted = s2.value.split(" ");
    if (s1Splitted[1] === s2Splitted[1]) {
      // if size type is the same, compare the number
      return parseFloat(s1Splitted[0]) > parseFloat(s2Splitted[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    // default : compare on size type Mb > Kb > Bytes
    return s1Splitted[1] > s2Splitted[1] ? -1 : 1;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="orderByExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="file in files | orderBy:'size':false:fileSizeComparator">
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        <td>{{file.size}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's the idea atleast, but it seems the comparator is not being used by the directive. Copying the code from angular documentation to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdk21c62/) also seems to be not working. Anyone know if this feature is depricated?

**UPDATED**

Fixed the code, figured out what was wrong : need angular 1.5.7 and return 1 or -1 in comparator instead of true/false

Comment: Also my code is a little different :  <tr ng-click="viewFiles({{files.id}})"
                            ng-repeat="files in FileObject | orderBy:fileOrder:reverse">
                            <td>{{files.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{files.size | Filesize}}</td>
                        </tr>

Comment: I have fixed my code, now it should be working. If you want me to help you with your specific code, you need to post it.